# Java words reverse

Tags: java, string, words

I am new to Java and I found a interesting problem which I wanted to solve. I am trying to code a program that reverses the position of each word of a string. For example, the input string = "HERE AM I", the output string will be "I AM HERE". I have got into it, but it's not working out for me. Could anyone kindly point out the error, and how to fix it, because I am really curious to know what's going wrong. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Count{
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static String in = ""; static String ar[];
void accept(){
    System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
    in = sc.nextLine();
}
void intArray(int words){
    ar = new String[words];
}
static int Words(String in){
    in = in.trim(); //Rm space
    int wc = 1;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i<in.length()-1;i++){

        if (in.charAt(i)==' '&&in.charAt(i+1)!=' ') wc++;
    }
    return wc;
}
void generate(){
    char c; String w = ""; int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<in.length(); i++){
        c = in.charAt(i);
        if (c!=' '){
          w += c;
        }
        else {
            ar[n] = w; n++;
        }

    }
}
void printOut(){
    String finale = "";
    for (int i = ar.length-1; i>=0;i--){
        finale = finale + (ar[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Reversed words: "  + finale);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Count a = new Count();
    a.accept();
    int words = Words(in);
    a.intArray(words);
    a.generate();
    a.printOut();
 }
}
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: It gives "nullHEREAMHERE"

Comment: Just use split and then reverse the list ;)

Comment: I assume you are taking the easy way and doing String[] aryoftext = "I AM HERE"; String[] temp = aryoftext.split(" "); for(int i = temp.length; i > 0; i--) System.out.println(temp[i]);

Comment: No, I know split function, but I want to learn how to code the manual way. I mean I should get to know the basics first, and then hopefully use the functions ;)

Comment: You should consider that reinventing the wheel is something programmers don't have time for. Nor should you. You have a vast world to explore out there... The basics won't get you job. Only knoeledge will

Comment: "I want to learn how to code the manual way" - that sounds both weird and irrational...

Comment: If you want to code at this low a level, do it in C. In Java it's self-defeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From adding debug output between each method call it's easy to determine that you're successfully reading the input, counting the words, and initializing the array.  That means that the problem is in `generate()`.

Problem 1 in `generate()` (why "HERE" is duplicated in the output): after you add `w` to your array (when the word is complete) you don't reset `w` to `""`, meaning every word has the previous word(s) prepended to it.  This is easily seen by adding debug output (or using a debugger) to print the state of `ar` and `w` each iteration of the loop.

Problem 2 in `generate()` (why "I" isn't in the output): there isn't a trailing space in the string, so the condition that adds a word to the array is never met for the last word before the loop terminates at the end of the string.  The easy fix is to just add `ar[n] = w;` after the end of the loop to cover the last word.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's what I wanted, it's solved now :)

Answer (score 3):

Got it. Here is my code that implements `split` and `reverse` from **scratch**.
The **split** function is implemented through iterating through the string, and keeping track of start and end indexes. Once one of the indexes in the string is equivalent to a " ", the program sets the end index to the element behind the space, and adds the previous substring to an `ArrayList`, then creating a new start index to begin with.

**Reverse** is very straightforward - you simply iterate from the end of the string to the first element of the string.

*Example*:

> Input: df gf sd
>   
> Output: sd gf df

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Count{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter string to reverse: ");
        String unreversed = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Reversed String: " + reverse(unreversed));
    }

    public static String reverse(String unreversed)
    {
        ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
        String reversed = "";
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < unreversed.length(); i++)
        {
            if (unreversed.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                end = i;
                parts.add(unreversed.substring(start, end));
                start = i + 1;
            }
        }

        parts.add(unreversed.substring(start, unreversed.length()));

        for (int i = parts.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reversed += parts.get(i);
            reversed += " ";
        }

        return reversed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Henry incorporated part of your code in here

Answer (score 2):

There is my suggestion :

```
    String s = " HERE AM I ";
    s = s.trim();
    int j = s.length() - 1;
    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = j; i >= 0; i--) {

        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c.isWhitespace(c)) {
            index = i;
            String r = s.substring(index+1, j+1);
            j = index - 1;
            builder.append(r);
            builder.append(" ");
        }
    }
      String r=s.substring(0, index);
      builder.append(r);
      System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the split function and then print from the end of the list to the front.

```
String[] splitString = str.split(" ");

for(int i = splitString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){

    System.out.print(splitString[i]);
    if(i != 0) System.out.print(' ');
}
```

Oops read your comment. Disregard this if it is not what you want.

Comment: And how do we do it without split()? That's my question. I got to know about Split for Herbert Schildt's book, but I don't want to use split

Comment: @MissionCoding is you don't want to use split - you should specify it in the question, that's a perfectly valid (and good) answer!

Answer (score 1):

This has a function that does the same as split, but not the predefined split function

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string : ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    // This splits the string into array of words separated with " "
    String arr[] = myOwnSplit(input.trim(), ' '); // ["I", "AM", "HERE"]

    // This ll contain the reverse string
    String rev = "";

    // Reading the array from the back
    for(int i = (arr.length - 1) ; i >= 0 ; i --) {
        // putting the words into the reverse string with a space to it's end
        rev += (arr[i] + " ");
    }

    // Getting rid of the last extra space
    rev.trim();

    System.out.println("The reverse of the given string is : " + rev);
}

// The is my own version of the split function
public static String[] myOwnSplit(String str, char regex) {

    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> spltedArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String word = "";

    // splitting the string based on the regex and bulding an arraylist
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++) {
        char c = arr[i];

        if(c == regex) {
            spltedArrayList.add(word);
            word = "";
        } else {
            word += c;
        }

        if(i == (arr.length - 1)) {
            spltedArrayList.add(word);
        }
    }

    String[] splitedArray = new String[spltedArrayList.size()];

    // Converting the arraylist to string array
    for(int i = 0 ; i < spltedArrayList.size() ; i++) {
        splitedArray[i] = spltedArrayList.get(i);
    }

    return splitedArray;
}
```